# Why is 32-bit regsvr32 invoked from inside Azure startup task?

Tags: windows, com, azure, 32bit-64bit, windows-server-2008-r2

My Azure role startup task is invoking a .cmd file:

```
<Startup>
    <Task commandLine="startup.cmd" executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple"/>
</Startup>
```

The .cmd file contains invokation of `regsvr32`:

```
//startup.cmd
regsvr32 PathToMyComServer\MyComServer.dll
```

for registering a 32-bit in-proc COM server.

Now on 64-bit systems there're two versions of `regsvr32` - one in SysWOW64 folder for 32-bit COM servers and one in System32 folder for 64-bit COM servers. Of course only the matching version of `regsvr32` can be used for any given in-proc COM server.

When I login onto my development Windows 2008 box and run `regsvr32` from a command line the 64-bit version is invoked, but when my startup task runs - both in Compute Emulator and in the live cloud - the 32-bit version is invoked and properly registers my in-proc COM server. This puzzles me.

Why is 32-bit version of `regsvr32` invoked in Azure startup task?

Comment: Presumably the application that is processing the startup file is 32-bit.  But I don't know why this would be the case.  If you just need a workaround, specify %SystemRoot%\sysnative\regsvr32 instead of just regsvr32.

Comment: I am interested to know the answer so would like to request if you had your problem resolved and what was the root cause.. thanks..

Comment: @Avkash: I currently don't have a fixable problem - the system just behaves this way, I just take that into account.

Comment: I wish i can get some free cycle to work on it and find resolution, not sure why but I am keep to go deep into it..

Answer (score 0):

Please try running your Startup task in as Real User Context as described in the link below, this should solve this problem:

http://www.davidaiken.com/2011/01/19/running-azure-startup-tasks-as-a-real-user/

On Azure VM i tried using PxExec tool to launch Regsvr32

> psexec regsvr32 -> Launches 32bit version of regsvr32
>   psexec -s regsvr32 -> Launched 64bit version of regsvr32

In both cases psexec was launched in 32bit mode on Azure VM running Win2K2008 64bit.

Thats why there is a reason I suggested to try launching startup task in real user context because on my 64bit machine, limited user rights, launching regsvr32.exe actually launch 32bit REGSVR32 and with admin user context same command launches 64bit regsvr32. Because startup task is not launched in real user context, I suspect this could be the one reason.

Another option is that you can use "PsExec -s" option to launch 64bit version of regsvr32 as well.